# React Uploading image in front-end (no back-end) only with AntD library

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, antd

I am trying to upload an image and display it in the front-end ( using React.js)

> I get this error `Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://localhost:8010/v2/5cc8019d300000980a055e76. (Reason: CORS request did not succeed). Status code: (null). 2`

I tried enabling  Cors
with these steps : npm install -g local-cors-proxy
here's the code maybe i missed something? :

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import './uploadBody.css';
import { InboxOutlined } from '@ant-design/icons';
import { message, Upload } from 'antd';

const { Dragger } = Upload;

const UploadImage = () => {
  const [uploadedImage, setUploadedImage] = useState(null);

  const props = {
    name: 'file',
    multiple: false,
    action: 'https://www.mocky.io/v2/5cc8019d300000980a055e76',
    onChange(info) {
      const { status, response } = info.file;
      if (status === 'done') {
        message.success(`${info.file.name} file uploaded successfully.`);
        setUploadedImage(response.url);
      } else if (status === 'error') {
        message.error(`${info.file.name} file upload failed.`);
      }
    },
  };

  if (uploadedImage) {
    return (
      <div className="container">
        <img src={uploadedImage} alt="Uploaded" />
      </div>
    );
  } else {
    return (
      <div className="container">
        <Dragger {...props}>
          <p className="ant-upload-drag-icon">
            <InboxOutlined />
          </p>
          <p className="ant-upload-text">Click or drag file to this area to upload</p>
          <p className="ant-upload-hint">
            Support for a single upload. Strictly prohibited from uploading company data or other banned files.
          </p>
        </Dragger>
      </div>
    );
  }
};

export default UploadImage;
```

Answer (score 0):

You are having a CORS problem. Not an ANTD problem.

To solve, just add to the header `'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'`to allow.

Also, the `mocky.io` url is not supposed to fully work with the provided code. So even if you bypass the CORS error, it will won't work. You need to mock an new upload url on the website to fully run the demo. If you open the link, you will see the test image used by ANTD.

```js
import React from 'react';
import './index.css';
import { UploadOutlined } from '@ant-design/icons';
import type { UploadProps } from 'antd';
import { Button, message, Upload } from 'antd';

const props: UploadProps = {
  name: 'file',
  action: 'https://www.mocky.io/v2/5cc8019d300000980a055e76',
  headers: {
    authorization: 'authorization-text',
    'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'
  },
  onChange(info) {
    if (info.file.status !== 'uploading') {
      console.log(info.file, info.fileList);
    }
    if (info.file.status === 'done') {
      message.success(`${info.file.name} file uploaded successfully`);
    } else if (info.file.status === 'error') {
      message.error(`${info.file.name} file upload failed.`);
    }
  },
};

const App: React.FC = () => (
  <Upload {...props}>
    <Button icon={<UploadOutlined />}>Click to Upload</Button>
  </Upload>
);

export default App;
```